# I am a beginner in Java programing and I want to print a String ,but due to mistake in coding I am not getting favorable output

Tags: java, string

```
 class Str {
   public static void main(String ss[]) {   
     String a="abcde";
     StringBuffer w=new StringBuffer(a);
     String h="";   
     for (int i=0;i<a.length();i++) {
       char e=a.charAt(i);
       if (Character.isDigit(e)) {
       } else {
         h=h+e;
       }
       System.out.println(h);
     }
   }
 }
```

output is:

```
a
ab
abc
abcd
abcde
```

But I want this output:

```
[a,ab,abc,abcd,abcde,b,bc,bcd,bcde,c,cd,cde,d,de,e]
```

Comment: System.out.print(h+",");

Comment: This is not a Java question, this is about how to properly structure an algorithm. Anyway, you need two loops.

Comment: For making your code readable I also suggest, you might want to name your variables/classes/methods in a descriptive manner. You will greatly profit from that - and it helps others to understand, what you want to achieve.

Answer (score 0):

You can put your for loop in a while loop. Remove the first character from `a` at the end of the for loop and itterate while `a.length > 0`

Answer (score 0):

This code which uses `String.substring` and the formatting of `List.toString` does the trick:

```
public static String print(String string) {
    List<String> strings = new ArrayList<String>();
    for (int i = 0; i < string.length(); ++i)
        for (int j = i+1; j <= string.length(); ++j)
            strings.add(string.substring(i,j));
    return strings.toString();
}
```

Example code:

```
public static void main(String ss[]) {
    System.out.println(print("abcde"));
}
```

Output:

```
[a, ab, abc, abcd, abcde, b, bc, bcd, bcde, c, cd, cde, d, de, e]
```

Answer (score 0):

i write this by using StringBuilder class

```
    public static void main(String arr[]){

    StringBuilder in= new StringBuilder("abcde");
    System.out.println(in.length());
    for (int i = 0; i < in.length(); i++) {
        for (int j = i; j <= in.length(); j++) {
                System.out.println(in.substring(i,j));
        }           
    }
}
```